# SLD Inverted Polygon

Tags: qgis, symbology, sld

I have a layer in QGIS that has a symbology as inverted polygon. However, I'm not able to export that in SLD (for showing it in GeoServer with geOrchestra). I have tried to write the code manually (since that QGIS doesn't export that type of symbology) but keep giving errors or doesn't display it as it should.
Any ideas on how to write correctly the SLD code for the inverted polygon?

Comment: If QGIS does not export that style into SLD it may indicate that it is something that SLD does not support. See  https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=22364 and https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=16700